# Joints in SpriteBuilder 1.1

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcode5, spritebuilder

like the post says, I am using SpriteBuilder 1.1.0-rc and I am having a problem with joints. The issue is that I drag the joints into the scene and then I link to the bodies, but when I build the project in Xcode, the joints are not working. I used to do joints by code in SpriteBuilder 1.0, and also in this version, but I want to know how I can do this only with SpriteBuilder, what am I missing?

Some screenshots over [here](http://forum.spritebuilder.com/t/joints-in-spritebuilder-1-1/1260)

Comment: have you tried enabling spring? what about distance joint? I can imagine that the spring is simply too "lax" so it may seem as if the bodies aren't under a constraint.

Comment: No, I tried that two options and nothing changed...

Comment: Finally I decided to return to the older versions... But thanks!